# Check selection not working anymore when programmatically opening rowEdit

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have this button, with the following event:

```
{ 
                        xtype: 'button',
                        scope: this,
                        text: 'Add',
                        itemId: 'btnadd',
                        icon      : 'images/add.png',

                        handler : function() 
                        {
                            var rec = new myStore({                             
                                language: ' ',
                                description: ' '
                            });    
                            this.tempStore.add(rec); //store associated with grid
                            //rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0); problems!
                        }
                    }
```

As long as that line is commented everything is ok, if I want to open the row editor a strange bug happens:
from then on it is not possibile to select cells anymore (I am using checkboxselection model).
How come??

Answer (score 1):

The method startEdit from the RowEditing plugin expects the record and the column header as parameters, not the position:
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-method-startEdit

Try `rowEditing.startEdit(rec);` or `rowEditing.startEdit(rec, 0);`